# Loading SVG (Scalable Vector Graphics) into AndEngine

Tags: svg, andengine

I am trying to load some SVG's into my game, but I am having truoble. I have tried reading the Android cook book, docs and answers from the forum, but I can't find a solution. I'm now at a state where I can actually load the images in and the game builds, but now I cannot display them. See as follows:

Loading in the .svg image:

```
BuildableBitmapTextureAtlas bitmapTextureAtlas = new BuildableBitmapTextureAtlas(
            engine.getTextureManager(), 1024, 1024, TextureOptions.BILINEAR); //setting up texture atlas

    try {
        this.mBuildableBitmapTextureAtlas
                .build(new BlackPawnTextureAtlasBuilder<IBitmapTextureAtlasSource, BitmapTextureAtlas>(
                        0, 0, 1));

    } catch (final TextureAtlasBuilderException e) {
        Debug.e(e);
    }



    SVGBitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.setAssetBasePath("gfx/game/");

    mLowResTextureRegion = SVGBitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory
            .createFromAsset(bitmapTextureAtlas, activity,
                    "spinningarrow.svg", 32, 32);
    mMedResTextureRegion = SVGBitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory
            .createFromAsset(bitmapTextureAtlas, activity, "spinningarrow.svg",
                    128, 128);

    // Create a high-res (256x256) texture region of svg_image.svg
    mHiResTextureRegion = SVGBitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory
            .createFromAsset(bitmapTextureAtlas, activity, "spinningarrow.svg",
                    256, 256);

    bitmapTextureAtlas.load();
```

Actually attaching it to the scene:

```
float currentSpritePosition = (WIDTH / ((SPRITE_SIZE) * SPRITE_COUNT)) + SPRITE_SIZE * 0.5f;

            Sprite lowResSprite = new Sprite(currentSpritePosition, HEIGHT / 2, SPRITE_SIZE, SPRITE_SIZE, rM.mLowResTextureRegion, rM.engine.getVertexBufferObjectManager());
            attachChild(lowResSprite);

            currentSpritePosition += SPRITE_SIZE;
            // Create & attach the med-res sprite to the scene (mid)
            Sprite medResSprite = new Sprite(currentSpritePosition, HEIGHT / 2, SPRITE_SIZE, SPRITE_SIZE, rM.mMedResTextureRegion, rM.engine.getVertexBufferObjectManager());
            attachChild(medResSprite);

            currentSpritePosition += SPRITE_SIZE;
            // Create & attach the high-res sprite to the scene (right side)
            Sprite hiResSprite = new Sprite(currentSpritePosition, HEIGHT / 2, SPRITE_SIZE, SPRITE_SIZE, rM.mHiResTextureRegion, rM.engine.getVertexBufferObjectManager());
            attachChild(hiResSprite);
```

This builds, but I cannot see the image; even if I hard code its coordinates.

The svg in question is at http://www.sendspace.com/file/nnjsfe

Comment: I don't really have any time to help much. Just looked at my code and I'm using something like this borderRT = SVGParser.parseSVGFromAsset(getAssets(), "geb/rt.svg"); where borderRT is of type SVG. Then I map that to a TextureRegion with borderRTTextureRegion = SVGBitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createFromSVG(BorderBitmapTextureAtlas, borderRT, 20, 60, 120, 50);

Comment: @carolclarinet don't advise people to delete questions once they have an answer. They should just plain answer it and leave the question and the answer here for those who have a similar problem later.